# in R: how to take subset of rows from one bigger table based on gene_id from another smaller table

Tags: r

I am new to R, so I might ask something which is very simple for advance R users. However, please help if you can. Thanks.

I have one bigger table with all normalised counts (A) and one smaller table with DRGs (B). First column for both tables is "Gene_ID". I need to create new table with normalised counts that will have all "Gene_ID" from the smaller table (B).

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer. So, advance apologies if I'm wrong.

Your question seems to be left join of table B and A.

Try this :

```
Subtable <- merge(x = TableB, 
               y = TableA[ ,c("Gene_ID", "Counts")], by = c("Gene_ID"), all.x = TRUE)
```

> You can specify columns for both tables by `[,c("col1","col2")]`.
>
> If you remove `all.x` it becomes an inner join.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

**Approach - 2**

Try this way,

`library(dplyr)`

`df.c <- inner_join(table.b[ ,c("Gene_id","a2")],table.a[ ,c("Gene_id","X3")], by = "Gene_id")`

Whatever column name you specify in bracket will be chosen.

There are other functions also, from this library, that would be of help. 
Try :

left_join, right_join or outer_join functions if your req changes.

Comment: Why didn't it work? Errors? Undesired results? It would help immensely with data sample and desired result. Please edit post accordingly. See link below tags.

Comment: Maybe I was not quite clear in my explanations. Table A has +20000 rows and 12 columns (different conditions of the experiment), while table B has ~500 rows and 6 columns (different from those in A). However, both tables have "Gene_Id" for the first column. I need new table similar as table A, but only for the subset of 500 genes present in table B. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I have made an update to the original answer. See if that works. Thanks

Comment: Dear Syed, thanks for your help. I am not sure I understand the presence of "a2", "X3", and "X1" in the code above. Can you please explain if you find some time. Thanks.

Comment: "a2", "X3","X1". . . . are all dummy column names from my dummy dataframe. Please replace them with your column names(the ones you seek in your final output).  **by = "Gene_id"** specifies "by which column to join"

Comment: Thanks Syed for your help :) I did it and I got this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(B, , c("Gene_ID", "baseMean", "log2FoldChange",  : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @DennyR Most probably, you are referring to the wrong column of the dataframe.`undefined columns selected` error occurs when that column is not present in the Data-frame you're referring to. Make sure the column names in `[....]` refers to the same Df